# convert time string XhYmZs to seconds in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string which comes in three forms:

```
XhYmZs or YmZs or Zs
```

where, h,m,s are for hours, mins, secs and X,Y,Z are the corresponding values.

How do I efficiently convert these strings to seconds in python2.7?

I guess I can do something like:

```
s="XhYmZs"
if "h" in s:
    hours=s.split("h")
elif "m" in s:
    mins=s.split("m")[0][-1]
```

... but this does not seem very efficient to me :(

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Do you mean that YmZs is something like 3m5s?

Comment: @StephenRauch: yes, that is correct.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: I do not agree with you that I want users to write code for me. I am just practicing with python, and as you can see I have clearly mentioned how to `efficiently` write such a code. Ofcourse, I can use a string split and split them into `ints` by looking or regexing for h,m,s - but I do not think this is efficient.

Comment: So, you not only want free code, you want _efficient_ free code?

Comment: if they are always going to be like `01h20m04s`  ie, double digit even if value less than 10 you can induce the possible format by checking length of the string

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: I have shown my attempt. As I said, doing it this way `does not` seem efficient to me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split on the delimiters you're interested in, then parse each resulting element into an integer and multiply as needed:

```
import re
def hms(s):
    l = list(map(int, re.split('[hms]', s)[:-1]))
    if len(l) == 3:
        return l[0]*3600 + l[1]*60 + l[2]
    elif len(l) == 2:
        return l[0]*60 + l[1]
    else:
        return l[0]
```

This produces a duration normalized to seconds.

```
>>> hms('3h4m5s')
11045
>>> 3*3600+4*60+5
11045
>>> hms('70m5s')
4205
>>> 70*60+5
4205
>>> hms('300s')
300
```

You can also make this one line by turning the `re.split()` result around and multiplying by 60 raised to an incrementing power based on the element's position in the list:

```
def hms2(s):
    return sum(int(x)*60**i for i,x in enumerate(re.split('[hms]', s)[-2::-1]))
```

Comment: This is so cool.. Wonder why I could not think of it :( Accepted the answer.. Thanks again and sorry if my question was a bit sparse the first time around - I was getting frustrated not able to think of a quick solution for this. urgh!

Comment: The original code is better for someone like me - I can then see what is going on :)

Comment: This does not handle scenarios without minutes: `hms("1h3s")` returns `63`. Also `hms("1h")` returns `1`

Comment: @ujjaldey - The spec says "I have a string which comes in three forms: `XhYmZs` or `YmZs` or `Zs`."

Answer (score 1):

Do not know how efficient this is, but this is how I would do it:

```
import re

test_data = [
    '1h2m3s',
    '1m2s',
    '1s',
    '3s1h2m',
]


HMS_REGEX = re.compile('^(\d+)h(\d+)m(\d+)s$')
MS_REGEX = re.compile('^(\d+)m(\d+)s$')
S_REGEX = re.compile('^(\d+)s$')


def total_seconds(hms_string):
    found = HMS_REGEX.match(hms_string)
    if found:
        x = found.group(1)
        return 3600 * int(found.group(1)) + \
               60 * int(found.group(2)) + \
               int(found.group(3))

    found = MS_REGEX.match(hms_string)
    if found:
        return 60 * int(found.group(1)) + int(found.group(2))

    found = S_REGEX.match(hms_string)
    if found:
        return int(found.group(1))

    raise ValueError('Could not convert ' + hms_string)

for datum in test_data:
    try:
        print(total_seconds(datum))
    except ValueError as exc:
        print(exc)
```

or going to a single match and riffing on TigerhawkT3's one liner, but retaining the error checking of non-matching strings:

```
HMS_REGEX = re.compile('^(\d+)h(\d+)m(\d+)s$|^(\d+)m(\d+)s$|^(\d+)s$')

def total_seconds(hms_string):
    found = HMS_REGEX.match(hms_string)
    if found:
        return sum(
            int(x or 0) * 60 ** i for i, x in enumerate(
                (y for y in reversed(found.groups()) if y is not None))

    raise ValueError('Could not convert ' + hms_string)
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I will go for @TigerHawks solution. Looks more clean.

Comment: @AJW - Yes, he is very smart, but kinda cranky...  You could still upvote my submission. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('3h4m5s', '%Hh%Mm%Ss').time()
datetime.time(3, 4, 5)
```

Since it varies which fields are in your strings, you may have to build a matching format string.

```
>>> def parse(s):
...   fmt=''.join('%'+c.upper()+c for c in 'hms' if c in s)
...   return datetime.datetime.strptime(s, fmt).time()
```

The [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) module is the standard library way to handle times.

Asking to do this "efficiently" is a bit of a fool's errand. String parsing in an interpreted language isn't fast; aim for clarity. In addition, *seeming* efficient isn't very meaningful; either analyze the algorithm or benchmark, otherwise it's speculation.

Comment: "String parsing in an interpreted language isn't fast" - It can be quite fast, particularly in a language meant for it, like Perl.

Comment: It's all relative; Perl inherits it from ed and awk, which are both written in C specifically for text processing. Python does provide regex parsing at the same level, but tends to lose some when people slice strings as it copies (buffers can avoid that). When you compare to Micron Automata, all software is slow. If performance really is a concern here, it's higly likely that a system approach is better; for instance, does it really need to be parsed into time, or is it enough to have a comparison function?

Answer (score 0):

My fellow pythonistas, please stop using regular expression for everything. Regular Expression is not needed for such simple tasks. Python is considered a slow language not because the GIL or the interpreter, because such mis-usage.

```
In [1]: import re
   ...: def hms(s):
   ...:     l = list(map(int, re.split('[hms]', s)[:-1]))
   ...:     if len(l) == 3:
   ...:         return l[0]*3600 + l[1]*60 + l[2]
   ...:     elif len(l) == 2:
   ...:         return l[0]*60 + l[1]
   ...:     else:
   ...:         return l[0]

In [2]: %timeit hms("6h7m8s")
5.62 µs ± 722 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [6]: def ehms(s):
   ...:    bases=dict(h=3600, m=60, s=1)
   ...:    secs = 0
   ...:    num = 0
   ...:    for c in s:
   ...:        if c.isdigit():
   ...:            num = num * 10 + int(c)
   ...:        else:
   ...:            secs += bases[c] * num
   ...:            num = 0
   ...:    return secs

In [7]: %timeit ehms("6h7m8s")
2.07 µs ± 70.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [8]: %timeit hms("8s")
2.35 µs ± 124 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [9]: %timeit ehms("8s")
1.06 µs ± 118 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [10]: bases=dict(h=3600, m=60, s=1)

In [15]: a = ord('a')

In [16]: def eehms(s):
    ...:    secs = 0
    ...:    num = 0
    ...:    for c in s:
    ...:        if c.isdigit():
    ...:            num = num * 10 + ord(c) - a
    ...:        else:
    ...:            secs += bases[c] * num
    ...:            num = 0
    ...:    return secs

In [17]: %timeit eehms("6h7m8s")
1.45 µs ± 30 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

see, almost 4 times as fast.

Answer (score 0):

There's a library [python-dateutil](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil) - `pip install python-dateutil`, it takes a string and returns a `datetime.datetime`.

It can parse values as `5h 30m`, `0.5h 30m`, `0.5h` - with spaces or without.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser


time = '5h15m50s'
midnight_plus_time = parser.parse(time)
midnight: datetime = datetime.combine(datetime.today(), datetime.min.time())
timedelta = midnight_plus_time - midnight
print(timedelta.seconds)  # 18950
```

It can't parse more than 24h at once though.